# List all Oracle statements executed for a given user on a given day

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Does anyone know how to get a listing of all the sql statements executed against the Oracle 12c database on a given day for a given OS User?  I have looked at v$sql but it doesn't seem to have the OS User info.  Example: I want see all the queries executed by OS User = 'xyz' on 06/21/2016 or on 06/15/2016.

Thanks

Comment: If you have an Enterprise License you can join [DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-335EC838-FEA0-4872-9E14-67C5A1908B35.htm#REFRN23400) and [DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-CB784B2E-FC47-40AA-9211-F886CFC6CAA5.htm#REFRN23448)

Comment: Unless you traced all the user's sessions or you have a crud-load of auditing enabled you probably can't get all of them.  You could potentially get a sampling of them (which would most likely include those that were called most often and those that took the longest) but that wouldn't be "all".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - An enterprise edition license with the performance and tuning pack option.  Not just a naked enterprise edition.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  - I looked at the two tables you listed.  It doesn't look like I can get the OS User account.